# Grails wkhtmltopdf plugin. Images are not displaying when exporting to pdf

Tags: pdf, grails, groovy, export, wkhtmltopdf

I'm exporting an html view to a pdf with [wkhtmltopdf plugin](https://github.com/rlovtangen/grails-wkhtmltopdf) and some of the images are not showing in the exported pdf file. The images are png files previously uploaded by users.

```
<img alt="img" src="${g.createLink(controller: 'imageController', action: 'getImageContent', id: user?.image?.id, absolute: true)}"/>
```

This code is working fine in the html view, calls the method and the image is displayed correctly, but when I try to export it to pdf, the images are not showing, everything else is exporting fine. Any alternatives/suggestions?

The method called:

```
def getImageContent(Long id) {
    def image = Image.findById(id)
    def imageName = image.name

    def file = new File("$uploadFolder/$imageName")
    if (file.exists()) {
        response.contentType = image.contentType
        response.outputStream.write(file.readBytes())

    } else {
        render status: 404
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike when Grails was supported by Spring and Pivotal, Grails no longer supports community plugins; all plugins maintained and supported by Grails are by Object Computing employees (or partners). This was actually confirmed at the ApacheCon this week when speaking with Grails contributors. So your best bet is to get in touch with the author and file a bug.

Comment: None of this is true.  We very much still support community plugins, new ones and updates to existing ones are published all the time, and we have no intention of ever changing that.  As far as I can tell no one at ApacheCon confirmed a claim like that and it would make sense that no one did, because it isn't true.